# How to find the max value in a list of objects by calling a function in Python

Tags: python, class, max

I would like to define a function in python that returns the max value of a calculated variable in a list of objects. I have first created a class and defined the new variable to calculate the average GDP per capita in thousands (self.percapita = 1000 * self.gdp / self.population):

```
class Country():    
  def __init__(self, name, population, gdp) :
    self.name = name
    self.population = population
    self.gdp = gdp
    self.percapita = 1000 * self.gdp / self.population
```

I enter the list of instances:

```
unitedstates = Country("unitedstates", 326766748, 19390600)
china = Country("china", 1415045928 , 12014610)
japan = Country("japan", 127185332, 4872135)

list = [unitedstates, china, japan]
```

I need your help to create a function that returns the country with the highest percapita and a tuple that contains the country's name and the percapita value:

```
 def highest_percapita(list) :
```

I know that the following code generates the desired outputs, but I need to create the above function instead:

```
 from operator import attrgetter
 highest_percapita = max(list, key=attrgetter('percapita'))
 print(highest_percapita.name)
 print(highest_percapita.name, highest_percapita.percapita)
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you have the code that solves the problem, what prevents you from putting this code in a function ?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
from operator import attrgetter


class Country():
    def __init__(self, name, population, gdp):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population
        self.gdp = gdp
        self.percapita = 1000 * self.gdp / self.population


def highest_percapita(list) :
    return max(list, key=attrgetter('percapita'))

unitedstates = Country("unitedstates", 326766748, 19390600)
china = Country("china", 1415045928 , 12014610)
japan = Country("japan", 127185332, 4872135)

lst = [unitedstates, china, japan]

print(highest_percapita(lst).name)
```

**Output**

```
unitedstates
```